# Do the iterators allocate memory such as pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, iterator

Do the iterators allocate memory such as pointers?

for example:

```
vector<int>v(100);
vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
```

Does "it" allocate memory and store the address of the first element of vector 'v' in it?
if so why can't we print the address of 'it' such as pointers?

Comment: what does it mean "can't we print the address of 'it' " ? Why you cannot?

Comment: `std::vector<int>::iterator` surely will consume certain storage as any class instance has at least 1 byte size. How the iterator is implemented is subject of the `std` library implementation. You cannot assume that it is a pointer. If there is no overloaded stream operator for the iterator then it cannot be "printed".

Comment: also your comparison with pointers is a bit moot. Pointers do not allocate memory for what they point to. Of course the pointer itself occupies some memory and the same is true for an iterator

Comment: i mean by print the address of 'it' is cout<<it .. it gives me compiler error

Comment: You can print the address of what the iterator "points" to: `std::cout << &*iter;` but, of course, only if `*iter` is a valid container element. I.e. this is Undefined Behavior for what `std::vector::end()` returns.

Comment: `cout<<it` gives compiler error because _there is no overloaded stream operator for the iterator_.

Comment: okay thank you, but i have more question please how many bytes does the iterator allocate? does it allocate memory of the vector type which here is <int> which means 4 bytes?

Comment: At least `sizeof(int*) = sizeof(std::size_t)`.

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are defined by the function they perform. How they perform that function is a `private` implementation detail. If an iterator wants to store an address, it can store an address. If it thinks storing the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything is useful, it can store 42 somewhere. If it wants to allocate 2MB of memory, it can – but end users are likely to notice and complain. The point is that implementation details are not standardized, and all you can expect from an iterator is a reasonably efficient implementation of its functionality.

You cannot print an implementation detail because that is not part of the required functionality. (This is a good thing. The fewer requirements on the iterator, the more freedom an implementation has to make the iterator efficient.)

If you think the implementation details are critical for your application, you probably want to write your own container and iterator classes so that you are not at the mercy of your library's implementors.

If you are just looking for a debugging aid, you are asking the wrong question. It is fairly simple to get the address of the object to which an iterator points, assuming it does actually point to an object. Dereference to get the object, then take the address. (The iterator `it` points to the object whose address is `&(*it)`.) No need to obsess over implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dynamic allocation here:

```
vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin();
```

You can think of assigning to a pointer. Iterator is not a pointer though to be exact.

Comment: Early implementations of `vector::iterator` actually were just typedefs to pointers, but I believe those are all obsolete now.